# How to return data from Web Api controller?

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api2

Hi I am developing restfull web api application. After inserting data into database i want to return 0 for success,1 for error and data as unique id assigned to the user. I want to return above data in json format. My requirement is i have to send data to controller in json format and receive data in json format.  I have following code and it is working but i want to ask few points here.
Below is my User_Creation controller code.

```
public result Post(Noor_Users users)
        {
            result obj = new result();
              if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    entityObject.Noor_Users.Add(users);
                    int result = entityObject.SaveChanges();
                    if(result==1)
                    {
                        obj.success = 0;
                        obj.id = 5;
                        return obj;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        obj.error = 1;
                        return obj;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    obj.error = 1;
                    return obj;
                }
            }
}
```

My service.js file contains below code.

```
app.service("UserCreation", function ($http) {
    this.saveSubscriber = function (sub) {
        return $http({
            method: 'post',
            data: JSON.stringify(sub),
            url: 'api/User_Creation',
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
    }
});
```

This is my controller.js code.

```
app.controller('UserCreation', function ($scope, UserCreation) {

    $scope.saveSubs = function () {
        var sub = {
            user_email: $scope.user_email,
            user_password: $scope.user_password,
        };
        var saveSubs = UserCreation.saveSubscriber(sub);
        saveSubs.then(function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data.data));
        }, function (error) {
            console.log('Oops! Something went wrong while saving the data.')
        })
    };
});
```

I am expecting response in json format as below.

●   status - 0 for success, 1 for failure.
●   data
    ○   id - unique id assigned to the user
●   error - error message if failed

This is working absolutelt fine. I have below line of code in webapiconfig.cs file

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
    .Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

With this line of code always i can receive data in json format. But in angularjs success call i need to stringify recieved data. If all my data is returning in json then again why i should convert it to json? Also someone can tell me is above logic is a good practice to return data? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. Add this two line of code on top of your WebApiConfig.cs

   ```
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
   {
        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
   ```
2. Edit you controller action with following one

   ```
   public IHttpActionResult Post(Noor_Users users)
   {
       result obj = new result();
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           entityObject.Noor_Users.Add(users);
           int result = entityObject.SaveChanges();
           if (result == 1)
           {
               obj.success = 0;
               obj.id = 5;
           }
           else
           {
               obj.error = 1;
           }
       }
       else
       {
           obj.error = 1;
       }

       return Ok(obj);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Still i doi need to have below line of code? JSON.stringify(data.data)

Comment: I write above code. Still in success call if i did not write json.stringify i am getting [object object]. So I am confused in which format my data is returning?

Comment: If i want to return list of items for example GET then how can i return through IHttpActionResult?

Comment: instead of `alert(JSON.stringify(data.data));` use `console.log(data)` inspect the object from your browser.